# C# client receives only one message from server

Tags: c#, client-server

I have simple client server application.

The code of client:

```
public class Client
{
    private TcpClient client;

    private NetworkStream stream;

    ...

    public Client(string clientName)
    {
        this.client = new TcpClient(); 
        this.client.Connect(this.Address, 13465);
        this.stream = this.client.GetStream();
    }

    public void Listening()
    {
        while (true)
        {
             BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
             string data = (string)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

             // do something with data
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Listening method is the one, which receives data and as you can see it has infinite loop.

The problem is, I can receive just one message from server. It means, that server sends me string, I receive this string. Server sends me another string and my Client does nothing.

I'm 100% sure, that server works properly, because I check it few times (even with Wireshark). Has someone any ideal, how to improve my application to receive all messages from server?

Comment: You already have asked about this problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731426/c-sharp-client-recieve-one-message-from-server

Comment: what does "client does nothing" mean? What does it look like it's doing in the debugger?

Comment: Yes I have, but is closed now. If I put breakpoint on `string data = (string)formatter.Deserialize(stream);` it enters just once. Nothing happen later. I tried flushing stream after every loop, but it has no effect.